# using mouse with sendInput in C

Tags: c, winapi

I would like to programmatically move and click the mouse using the windows API in C. I have searched google high and low and can't find any sendInput tutorials for plain C. All I can find is C#/C++. I have little experience with the windows API and would love a great tutorial that would cover sendInput! Thanks!

Comment: The C++ version will be appropriate, this isn't different since Winapi is C based.

Comment: You should leave that as an answer so I can mark you as correct! :p

Comment: you can just accept your answer, I don't think Hans needs the rep!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hans Passant was right with C++ code being almost identical. Here's what I ended up with:

```
INPUT input;
input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
input.mi.mouseData = 0;
input.mi.dx = x * (65536 / GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)); //x being coord in pixels
input.mi.dy =  y * (65536 / GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)); //y being coord in pixels
input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));
```

Comment: One very important thing to note is that you should be forcing 65536 to a float otherwise your screen size conversion will be off by several pixels.  65536.0f for better accuracy.

Comment: @Error454 Do you know why dx and dy must have that strange format for absolute movement ? Relative move on the other hand need dx and dy to be pure pixel count.

Comment: @mini-me Just the way msft decided to do things.  Their coordinate system is (0,0) for top left and (65535,65535) for bottom right.

Comment: One other thing to keep in mind is to make sure you set the time field in the MOUSEINPUT structure (probably to 0).  We weren't setting it in our code (and therefore it was a random number) and this was causing the display to go to sleep since apparently the random number looked like "this mouse event was a really long time ago" so since there hasn't been activity since then it is time to go to sleep.

Comment: @Error454, as long as you clamp the input x,y coordinates to sane values to avoid integer overflow, multiplying by 65536 (AKA `<< 16`) _before_ dividing by the screen metrics will fix any rounding issues without resorting to floats.

Comment: Does anybody know how to make the same code on Python ?

Comment: @Error454: You'd also have to add `0.5f`, to get the closest value, prior to conversion to `int`. Alternatively, simply call [MulDiv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383718.aspx), and have the system deal with all those intricacies (including overflows).