# winapi mouse_event wrong coords

Tags: c++, winapi, mouseevent

I tried to make an autoClicker that record where I put my mouse and then click the exact coordinated but in the end it clicks the same number of clicks on the last spot that my mouse was.

```
const int WAIT_INTERVAL = 5;
const int CLICK_POINTS = 5;
POINT mouse[CLICK_POINTS];
int clicks;
bool didGetPos;

for (int i = 1; i <= CLICK_POINTS; i++)
    {
        cout << i << " spot" << endl;
        Sleep(3000);
        didGetPos = GetCursorPos(&mouse[i - 1]);

        if (!didGetPos)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (didGetPos)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < CLICK_POINTS; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < clicks; j++)
            {
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, mouse[i].x, mouse[i].y, 0, 0);
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, mouse[i].x, mouse[i].y, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *This function has been superseded. Use SendInput instead.*

Comment: Didnt help.. still same last spot

Comment: Update your code to show your use of SendInput and maybe someone will help you.

Comment: You have to convert the coordinates: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4555214/4603670

Comment: @Barmak only if MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE is specified

Answer (score 1):

You did not include the `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` flag. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms646260.aspx) says:

> The dx and dy parameters contain normalized absolute coordinates. If not set, those parameters contain relative data: the change in position since the last reported position. This flag can be set, or not set, regardless of what kind of mouse or mouse-like device, if any, is connected to the system.

You are passing absolute coordinates and so need to include the `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` flag.

Of course you should heed the documentation and stop using this superseded function. Use `SendInput`.